# bash process running in the background

Tags: bash

I'm connecting to a remote server running Ubuntu 16.04 using ssh.  I'm running nodemon in a bash session but my network connection drops out if I walk away from my computer or close my laptop.  This locks up my sessions and I have to close the terminal window.  When I reconnect I'm unable to restart nodemon because it's running as a process in the background.
Is there a way to re-open the bash window that locked up?  What I've been doing is killing the nodemon process or restarting the system.  I'm hoping there's a simpler way.

Comment: Have you tried using a keepalive for your SSH connection? Most servers will kill the connection  after a fairly short time of inactivity.

Comment: you can use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

Comment: or even `tmux`, which I tend to prefer over `screen`...

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU screen. It runs a virtual terminal that stays open even if you loose your connection.

On the server, enter `screen -S myscreen` and do your normal command line work. When you disconnect, just open a new ssh connection to the server an execute `screen -r myscreen`. Your old session will be there as if you never left it.

You can manually leave the screen whithout killing it, by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the utility 'screen.' 
You can install it in Ubuntu with:

```
apt-get install screen
```

Or in Red Hat / CentOS with:

```
yum install screen
```

Then you can just enter the command screen to start a session. Then you can start whatever script you need to stay running regardless of disconnects.  Ctrl-A+Ctrl-D detaches you from the session. Then `screen -r` reconnects to it.   You can also preceed a command with `screen -d -m` and that process will start in a screen session.